# Date in London time different to GMT

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs

Using the JavaScript library `moment-timezone`, why don't these two statements both evaluate to 0?

```
> moment("1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT").unix()
0

> moment.tz("1970-01-01 00:00:00", "Europe/London").unix()
-3600
```

At first I thought it was due to Daylight Saving Time but surely London is the same as GMT in winter?

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct output.  In 1970, London was one hour ahead of UTC.

Reference Here: 
https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/uk/london?year=1970